# Virtual Repeater and Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, angular-material

**The Question:**

What is the canonical/preferred way to locate the [Virtual Repeaters](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat) in Protractor?

**The Story:**

In the Angular Material design there is a [Virtual Repeater](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat) that helps to improve the rendering performance with the help of dynamic reuse of rows visible in the viewport area. Sample:

```
<div class="md-virtual-repeat-offsetter" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
    <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item ng-binding ng-scope flex" flex="">0</div>
    <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item ng-binding ng-scope flex" flex="">1</div>
    <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item ng-binding ng-scope flex" flex="">2</div>
</div>
```

At the moment, I have to use [`by.css`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) location technique:

```
$$('[md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems"]');
```

**Bonus Question:**

Is there a way to make `by.repeater` also work with `md-virtual-repeat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`findRepeaterRows()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L169) and [`repeaterMatch()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L147) built-in functions, `by.repeater` locator uses CSS selectors to search for different "repeat"-like attributes with different prefixes:

```
ng-repeat
ng_repeat
data-ng-repeat
x-ng-repeat
ng:repeat
```

Then, it strips all the filters, tracking (`track by`), aliases (`as`) and then checks what repeater value are we trying to match.

In other words, *`by.repeater` at this moment is not going to find virtual repeaters*.

Created a feature request here:

- [by.repeater to match virtual repeaters](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2804)

---

At this moment, taking into account that *virtual repeaters don't support advanced syntax elements* as `track` or `as`, I think using a CSS selector is good enough:

```
$$('[md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems"]');
```

Comment: Sorry I don't actually see an answer here? Using `$$` doesn't work because html doesn't exist for later rows until scrolling down. The advice in the feature request was to depend on third parties to provide page objects, which would almost surely never happen

Comment: @luker02 sorry, there is not much to add here. This is just the state of things with visual repeaters in protractor.

Comment: no problem, thanks. We wrote a recursive function to scroll down using `protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN` until the element became visible or a retry threshold was hit. Slow & not recommended for large lists, but got the job done ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯